# Does Python(2.7)'s interactive shell have an equivalent to bash's "!!" (bang bang)?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

I'm used to typing `!!` in bash when I want to reference the last command executed in that shell.

```
$ ls -la  
drwxr-xr-x   4 me  wheel    136 Jan 19  2013 wireshark_stuff  
... (etc) ...  
-rw-r--r--   1 me  wheel     11 Mar 13 13:51 old_PS1  
$ !! |grep for_something_in_those_results  
ls -la |grep for_something_in_those_results  
/grep_results
```

Is there a way to do this in python?

```
>>> complicated_dict.['long_key_name'][0]  
(response)  
>>> my_func(!!)
```

This would get really handy as the interpreter commands become increasingly complicated. Sure, I could just use a plethora of local variables - but sometimes it's handy to just invoke the last thing run...

Comment: Underscore works in the shell for this purpose.

Comment: Good Lord you people are fast.

Comment: Underscore doesn't reexecute anything, though; it's just a variable bound to the value of the previous expression.

Comment: @poke; Definitely the same answer, but the referenced potential dupe refers to Matlab/Mathematica. I recommend leaving this here to route bash-familiar users like myself to the accepted answer there. (I will also accept the first answer here, which I commented on below, when I am able.)

Comment: @chepner Good to know, as bash (I believe) actually evaluates `!!` to the content of the last executed command. A good nuance to understand - thanks.

Comment: @user3.1415927 Don’t worry, a question being closed as a duplicate does not mean that it’s not useful or otherwise wrong. It just means that it has already been covered elsewhere; closed questions are usually kept around as an additional entry point to a topic, so yeah, we’ll keep this :)

Comment: It does; `!!` is part of history expansion, so it really just expands to the last *command*, and (by default) executes it. (I have the option to just display the command in the buffer, but that's beside the point.) I think there is a Readline function that will fetch and execute the last command, but I have to research it a little.

Comment: I’d say the `_` is more similar to accessing the exit code of the previous command. Output in shells is usually produced by printing to the stdout. That content is of course no longer accessible; same as printed content in Python.

Comment: To be clear then, `_` doesn't actually reference the last executed expression, but rather the output/return of the last executed expression? If that's the case, then technically `_` is not the same as `!!` - it references the outcome, not the input....  
I would still like to know if there is something to do the same history expansion as is performed in bash when `!!` is invoked.

Answer (score 4):

The value of the last expression evaluated in the Python shell is available as `_`, ie the single underscore.

Comment: Holy smokes you people are fast. I can't even accept the answer for 12 more minutes!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `_` character to reference the last calculated value, and use it in other calculations:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> x + 10
15
>>> _
15
>>> _ + 2
17
```

Answer (score 1):

Using default Readline bindings, <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> is probably the closest exact equivalent to `!!`; the first key fetches the previous command; the second executes it. You can probably add a custom binding to `.inputrc` to execute both functions with one keystroke. Note, though, this is entirely line-oriented; if you try to use this following a multi-line `for` statement, for example, you'll only get the very last line of the body, not the entire `for` statement.

The `_` variable stores the result of the last evaluated expression; it doesn't reevaluate, though. This can be seen most clearly with something like `datetime.datetime.now`:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 22, 14, 14, 50, 360944)
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 22, 14, 14, 51, 665947)
>>> _
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 22, 14, 14, 51, 665947)
>>> _
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 22, 14, 14, 51, 665947)
>>> _
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 22, 14, 14, 51, 665947)
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 22, 14, 14, 58, 404816)
```

Answer (score 0):

Up-arrow / return!  As long as your interpreter was compiled with `readline` support.